# Angularjs localStorage: Cannot read property '$default' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-storage

I'm working with Ionic and AngularJs and I need to save some data in localStorage so I installed ngStorage with bower and I imported it in index.html, but I have got this error when I initialize the `$localStorage`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$default' of undefined
```

Here is how I initilized it

```
$localStorage = $localStorage.$default({
  carrello: []
});
```

Here is the method for add data to the localStorage

```
$scope.addDisco = function(index, carrello){
    $scope.selectedDisco = $scope.listaDischi[index];
     StorageService.add($scope.selectedDisco);
}
```

and here is the factory

```
app.factory ("StorageService", function ($localStorage) {

var _getAll = function () {
  return $localStorage.things;
};

var _add = function (thing) {
  $localStorage.things.push(thing);
}

var _remove = function (thing) {
  $localStorage.things.splice($localStorage.things.indexOf(thing), 1);
}

return {
    getAll: _getAll,
    add: _add,
    remove: _remove
  };
})
```

I usually work with $window.sessionStorage so I never worked with this type of data storage so every ideas are welcome.
ty

Comment: Do you have ngStorage module included to app? 
angular.module('app', [
    'ngStorage'
])

Comment: @Daveus why you need ngStorage ? just use $window.localStorage. [Try this link](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/25/angularjs-real-time-model-persistence-using-local-storage/)

Comment: @tomek550 yes of course...the problem is just the initialization of the sessionStorage

Comment: @anoop I don't want just because I'm studying Angular2 and sessionStorage doesn't exist in it so is just for exercise

Comment: okay.. [have a read](https://medium.com/@petehouston/awesome-local-storage-for-ionic-with-ngstorage-c11c0284d658), might be helpful for you.

Comment: Where are you initializing it?  Is $localStorage injected into that specific function?

Comment: I resolved it! the problem were that I initialized with the array "carrello" but in the factory I use the variable "things"